# cordova admob pro not working at all in android

Tags: android, cordova

I have really followed all the instructions given by the plugin, also tried many tutorials, but it is not showing up. I have attached my app.js file, it is using ionic framework.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
/**** Admob Pro ****/
  var admobid = {};
    // select the right Ad Id according to platform
    if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
        admobid = { // for Android
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz'
        };
    } else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = { // for iOS
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz'
        };
    } else {
        admobid = { // for Windows Phone
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zzzzzzzzzzzz'
        };
    }

    if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId:admobid.banner, 
        position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
        isTesting: true, // TODO: remove this line when release
        autoShow:true} );
      /**** Admob Pro ****/
    });
  })
```

Please help my find the mistake...

Answer (score 3):

I know you did this correctly, but just to be clear,
please make sure that your banner id is correct.

Comment: double checked, it is correct